# How to import user roles and pictures using the Migrate_d2d module?

Tags: migrations

I haven't been able to find any clear instructions for how to include roles & user pictures in the user migration using the migrate_d2d module.

I *have* found a number of links with *some* information, but it is all incomplete - or at least it is incomplete for someone who isn't a programmer...

The "Role Migration" page on Drupal.org (https://www.drupal.org/node/1819698) has as its first step: "Instantiate the appropriate role migration class."

Problem is, I have no idea how to do that...

I've tried to find examples of doing this but have found none.

The Migrate_d2d module has some example code in it that does a pretty good job of describing how to import users, vocabularies, nodes, & menus, but it is silent on how to bring along roles - which is vital to getting most of the rest of a site to work.

I need some help. Every source I've found seems to assume one or two things I just don't know - or maybe I do, but don't understand how to apply them in this case. Any specific, full examples - *not* the snippets I've seen a bunch of that don't give enough context - of how to get the user import to include role mappings would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following block of code allowed me to import user pictures, roles, & users, and connected them all properly:

```
  /*
   * User Picture Migration
   */
  $api['migrations']['UserPictures'] = $common_arguments + array(
    'description' => t('Migration of user pictures from Drupal 6.'),
    'class_name' => 'DrupalPicture6Migration',
    'default_uid' => 1, // The default owner id if owner is not present
    'source_dir' => 'http://www.example.com',
    'destination_dir' => 'public://',
  );

  /**
   * Register the role migration
   */
  $api['migrations']['UserRoles'] = $common_arguments + array(
    'description' => t('Import Drupal 6 roles.'),
    'class_name' => 'DrupalRole6Migration',
    'role_mappings' => array(
      'unconfirmed' => 'unconfirmed',
      'contributor' => 'contributor',
      'superadmin' => 'superadmin',
    ),
  );

  /**
   * Register the user migration.
   */
  $api['migrations']['Users'] = $common_arguments + array(
    'description' => t('Migration of users from Drupal 6'),
    'class_name' => 'DrupalUser6Migration',
    'picture_migration' => 'UserPictures',
    'role_migration' => 'UserRoles',
  );
```

I looked at probably 30-40 different search results - and some let's-see-what-this-does stabs in the dark - before I finally got things working, but there were 3 main resources I used:

- https://smbjorklund.no/how-migrate-content-drupal-6-7-using-migrated2d-part-1
- https://www.drupal.org/node/1813498
- The migrate_d2d_example module contained in the migrate_d2d module itself.